# Import 76 MB xlsb file makes Import Dialog crash

Tags: sql-server

I have xlsb file which is around 76 MB. I need import this data into Sql Server. I am trying with differnt options to import including,

1. Sql Server Native Client
2. Sql Server Oledb Provider
3. .Net Framework Provider for Sql Server

But it keeps crashing with this error inside event viewer,

```
Faulting application name: DTSWizard.exe, version: 15.0.1900.63
Faulting module name: MSVCR100.dll, version: 10.0.40219.325
Exception code: 0x40000015
Fault offset: 0x0008d6fd
Faulting process id: 0xef9c
Faulting application start time: 0x01d6abbe6621199c
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\SSIS\150\Binn\DTSWizard.exe
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\MSVCR100.dll
Report Id: 1dfd6110-8990-4002-82d9-dd75f6110ef3
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

What else I can do to import this file?

Comment: there are some options https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/relational-databases/import-export/import-data-from-excel-to-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @nbk very nice resource thanks

Comment: I just found that if I make the file a single sheet and convert it into xslx format it starts working.

Comment: I've had hit or misses using SSMS's import data wizards with Excel files, especially CSVs. For the CSVs, at least as a workaround, I found if I open it in Notepad++ and re-save the file without making any changes it fixes it, and then the import wizards end up working. Hopefully this helps someone else if they've experienced the same problem (and in general re-saving other files might be a workaround too.)